# Importing from Excel to Visma Contracting

Tags: excel

My company is using this program called Visma Contracting. This program is used to type inn a product number (example: 10 240 75) and how many of this item was used (example: 4). So these numbers we (me and my co-workers) put into an excel sheet and deliver to  the guy in charge of the systematizing these (A column being product number, an B column being the used amount). From there it is **retyped** from excel to Visma. This is madness! There must be a way for the two programs to talk to each other? I have talked to the Visma support and they are giving me nothing else then a no. I wish i could give more info about this Visma stuff, but i fear that it is a locked program. I have also been searching around for a 3rd party software that can eliminate this massive annoying problem, with no luck. Does **anyone** have **anything** that might ease my itch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds impossible but...

If you want to try blind keystrokes check out [Mouse and Keystroke Recorder](http://www.kratronic.com/tools/recorder/) I have some experience automating stuff with this program.  It works sometimes with varying degrees of reliability.

Be forewarned that nobody recommends this as it could cause problems. It simply plays back keystrokes without being aware of what it is doing. When used with care it can work but it could be dangerous.

Or use SendKeys from Excel VBA; that might work better as the data is already in Excel. But the same warnings apply. Use at your own risk.